# Why doesn't JQuery $.grep() work with selectors?

Tags: jquery

It seems odd that grep does not work with an optional selector argument - the existing way you call grep seems to fall outside JQuery conventions. In other words, this works:

```
$.grep($('div'), function(div) { return div.className == 'section' });
```

This does not:

```
$('div').grep(function(div) { return div.className == 'section' });
```

Furthermore, because of this it becomes tricky to search a list of tags - the first line of code, while it works, returns a flat array instead of a nice chainable JQuery object you can call .css() etc on.

Is there a good reason for grep to work this way in JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are looking for is the second (callback) variant of [`$.fn.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

It works much the same way as `$.grep`, but acts on a jQuery object, and returns a jQuery object of all of the elements that returned `true` from the callback function, e.g.:

```
$('div')
.filter(function() {
    return this.className == 'section'
})
.css( ... ) ;
```

Comment: It seems odd that they do the same thing, just one for a collection of tags and the other for arrays. There's no harm in using the same name for both, and I'd argue it's actually confusing to have to use different names depending on whether you're filtering a plain array or a selection of tags.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `jQuery.grep()` is meant to be an implementation of `array.Filter`, similar to how `jQuery.inArray()` is meant to provide an implemention of `array.indexOf`. Hence, they don't follow other jQuery method conventions.

As someone else has pointed out, `filter()` exists for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `$.grep` method is one of the [utility methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/) intended to be used with arrays. There are other methods following the same pattern, like `$.each`, `$.map`, `$.inArray` and `$.merge`.

If you want methods that work on element collections you should look at the [traversing methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/), corresponding to the `$.grep` method would be the [filter method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

---

Also, if you happen to have an array of elements, you can easily put them in a jQuery object:

```
$($.grep($('div'), function(div) { return div.className == 'section' }))
```